# String processing arguments

Tags: vba, ms-word

```
Public Function GetAllUndershoreVaues() As Collection
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Dim colAux1 As Collection
Dim sentence As Range
Dim w As Words
For Each sentence In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    For Each w In sentence.Words
        If (InStr(w, "-") > 0) Then
            If Right(w, "-") Then
               colAux1.Add w, UCase$(w)
            Else
                Set colAux1 = Nothing
            End If
        Else
        Set colAux1 = Nothing
        End If
    Next
Next
    Set GetAllUndershoreVaues = colAux1
    Set colAux1 = Nothing
    Set sentence = Nothing
    Set w = Nothing
End Function
```

getting Compile error:

> Argument not optional

Comment: a) You need to initialize the `colAux1` collection and b) don't set it to nothing if the condition is false.

Comment: "Right(w, "-")".  This is not the correct usage of the VBA Right method.

Answer (score 0):

Looping through every word in every storyrange is incredibly inefficient. Try something along the lines of:

```
Public Function GetAllUndershoreVaues() As Collection
Dim colAux1 As Collection, Rng As Range, StrItem As String
Set colAux1 = New Collection
For Each Rng In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
  With Rng
    With .Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Text = "-*>"
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Forward = True
      .Format = False
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Do While .Find.Execute = True
      StrItem = Split(.Text, "-")(1)
      colAux1.Add StrItem, UCase$(StrItem)
      .Collapse (wdCollapseEnd)
    Loop
  End With
Next
Set GetAllUndershoreVaues = colAux1: Set colAux1 = Nothing
End Function
```